# Sum over columns and divide by number of non-zero values in row in r

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I want to aggregate(sum) columns and then divide the aggregate by the number of non-zero values in each row.
`sample data`:

```
col 1    col 2    col 3          

    0         0        0
    0         0        0
    0.5       0.5      0 
    0         0.25     0
    0.583     0.583    0.583
```

`expected output:`

```
sum

    0
    0
    0.5
    0.25
    0.583
```

Grateful for any tips on how to do this in r
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(text="0         0        0
                       0         0        0
                       0.5       0.5      0 
                       0         0.25     0
                       0.583     0.583    0.583")

df2 <- data.frame(results=apply(df,1,function(x){
ifelse(any(x!=0),sum(x)/length(x[x!=0]),0)}))
```

output:

```
df2
 results
1   0.000
2   0.000
3   0.500
4   0.250
5   0.583
```